# Download File with Progressbar showDialog - error

Tags: android, download, android-progressbar, showdialog

i keep getting this error telling me to suppress my showdialog code for my progress bar.

now what can i do to fix this, also i dont want to use any other way. im trying to learn showdialog for downloads

here my code

```
public class download extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://practicalbuddhist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Synapses-Image-for-March-17-2010-Blog-Entry.jpg";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Running Download Test...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Downloadtest.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

}
}

Comment: when i try this on my phone, it doesnt do anything, and i check if the file was on my sdcard which it wasnt.

Comment: hey sorry here the right code:       10-31 16:51:20.661: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(211): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()

Comment: What it tells you? Is it telling u that `showDialog` is a deprecated method? If so, which API version are using to build your project? It seemed u're using `showDialog` on a newer version of Android, which recommends you to build dialog using `Fragments`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dialog class methods directly not the Activity helper methods.

In the Dialog API guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html they say explicitly to do not use ProgressDialog but use a custom layout with a ProgressBar.

On the other hand you could just use the DownloadManager to download files asynchrously. Check https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java for a simple example even with notifications.

If you still wants this method check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/ for a simple example using a ProgressDialog-